# Android studio show java code or binary code in Layout file (.xml)

Tags: xml, android-studio, layout, android-edittext

it's been a long time since I worked on an Android Project with Android Studio. All work fine.
Today I wasn't able to open .xml file ( layout, values: string.xml, color.xml,..) in android studio editor.
Android studio shows sometimes java code in .xml file,  binary code or other xml code instead of the one from the opened file.

==>Invalidate cash and restart Android studio, didn't solve the problem.
==>delete .idea and .iml file and imported project, didn't solve the problem either

However, if I open a .java class it opens with the correspondent code. This problem doesn't occur with Java files.

But Some of the java instructions are underlined as an error but aren't really an error. I can debug projects, run it on my USB device and also export as an APK.
My only problem is with the project resource files ( .xml)

[layout file with bad content opened by android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeHVX.jpg)

But when I open the same file with Notepad++, the code is fine

[layout file with good content opened by notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Huj.jpg)

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3

help me please!

Comment: hi... i solved my problem by uninstalling et reinstalling Android studio completly...

Answer (score 7):

Here's what worked for me.
First  Close Android Studio.

and  Go to

**C:\Users\your_user_name\ .AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches**

Delete the caches folder.

And open the android studio. And your project is now open without any problem.

Comment: Thanks @Abhingn01, i would apply your solution the next time i encounter this problem

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be having exactly this problem (and no answers found so far on SO) with exactly the same build as you have, except that I am running on Windows 10:

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

The other difference I have is that in fact the problem can occur with both layout and java code files (i.e. you open a java code file and it shows you some other file contents - could be layout, .iml, anything actually).

The problem seems to occur every few days and there seems to be only two solutions I find so far:

1. The solution you describe (re-install everything) or...
2. (Quick and Dirty) - just keep working as normal (as long as you can still build debug etc.) until you need to edit one of the files or dependencies of that file which is not opening correctly in Android Studio and therefore causing inline compilation errors (red underline thingies).  Shut down Android Studio and make a copy of the offending file before deleting from the file system.  Start Android Studio and copy the (backed up) file back to the java/layout file path and sync if necessary if Android Studio does not immediately pick it up.  Viola!

Answer (score 1):

this solution work for me perfectly

- close android studio
- delete this file: `C:\Users\your_user_name\ .AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches`
- open android studio again

and that's it

it happened for me on unexpected system restart

Answer (score 0):

me too have same encounter there.
Let me share this, hoping it'll be help you

**Problem**
After searching a few and questioning a few friends, (*my case*) they told me it was caused either data corruption on AS due to electricity problem or attacked by virus.

I believed it caused by corruption, so i had to re copy-paste my *well looked* code into AS again, but no.
Once you re copy-paste the code, problem not solved!
Your code will shows a bunch of warning and etc.
The problem itself, is the Editor Android Studio!

My hypothesis, i thought that i forcing close AS on some process that make it corrupted.

**Solve**
I update Android Studio (*mine 3.2*) to 3.3.1 (***newest***) and everything works well like before.
Hope it helps!

Comment: that is the solution what i do

Comment: So please kindly accept either of these answer sir, so the other know the solution when they face the same problem